# Moq: Return mock object with most implementation created

Tags: moq

I want to mock my Repository object in such a way that it can still do actual DB retrieve operations. Only for Saving operations, I wanted to setup to return mock data since I don't want it to save into the DB.

How should I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make your Save operation virtual and override it in a subclass which you use in your tests rather than using Moq?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your unit tests should never actually go out to the database (it is all right for integration tests, but that is a larger topic). What you want to do is pretty straightforward with Moq, though:

```
public class MyRepo
{
      public virtual string Save(MyClass foo)
      {
          // perform save...
      }
 }

 public class MyService
 {
       public MyRepo Repo { get; set; }

       public string VerifyAndSave(MyClass foo)
       {
            // verify foo...
            return new Repo.Save(foo);
       }
 }

 public class MyClass()
 {
      public string SomeData { get; set; }
 }
```

Notice the `virtual` modifiers on the methods--these are important for Moq to be able to stub them.

In your tests you could then do something like this:

```
 [TestClass]
 public class SomeTests
 { 
     private Mock<MyRepo> MockRepo { get; set; }
     private MyService Target { get; set; }

     [TestInitialize]
     public void Setup()
     {
         MockRepo = new Mock<MyRepo>();
         Target = new MyService();
         Target.Repo = MockRepo.Object;
     }

     [TestMethod]
     public void MyTest()
     {
           const string expectedOutput = "SAVED";
           MyClass exampleData = new MyClass();

           MockRepo.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<MyClass>())).Returns(expectedOutput);

           Target.VerifyAndSave(exampleData);

           MockRepo.Verify(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<MyClass>()));
     }
 }
```

The chained calls of `Setup` and `Returns` in this case would guarantee that the calling method (i.e. `VerifyAndSave`) would see the value that you specified--"SAVED" in this case.

For more examples, take a look at the [Moq quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) docs.